# why google chrome shuts down after closing the terminal?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, shutdown

I have to use Google chrome while running the terminal in the background. In fact if I press ctrl+c it shuts down with the Google chrome too. Why is it happening? Is there any way I can resume Google chrome after closing the terminal?If I try to close it, Google chrome gets closed too.

Comment: if you start the chrome from the terminal and if you press `ctrl+c` it will terminate the application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
<your_app> & disown
```

In this case:

```
google-chrome & disown
```

*Explanation:*

> In the bash shell, the disown builtin command is used to remove jobs from the job table, or to mark jobs so that a SIGHUP signal is not sent to them if the parent shell receives it (e.g. if the user logs out).

<sub>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disown_(Unix))</sub>

Comment: The semicolon prevents it to work, it's just `<your_app> & disown`

Comment: so should I open another terminal for this command or should I just type this in the same terminal that is controlling google chrome?

Comment: Use the command to start Google Chrome.